# Proportions by group with survey weights

Tags: r, data.table, survey

```
data = data.frame(ID = 1:1000,
                  GROUP = factor(sample(1:5, rep = T)),
                  CAT = factor(sample(1:5, rep = T)),
                  DOG = factor(sample(1:5, rep = T)),
                  FOX = factor(sample(1:5, rep = T)),
                  MOUSE = factor(sample(1:5, rep = T)),
                  WEIGHT = round(runif(1000)*100,0)
                  )

data_WANT = data.frame(VARS = c("CAT", "DOG", "FOX", "MOUSE", "WEIGHT"),
                       GROUP1_N = NA,
                       GROUP1_PROP = NA,
                       GROUP2_N = NA,
                       GROUP2_PROP = NA,
                      GROUP3_N = NA,
                       GROUP3_PROP = NA,
                       GROUP4_N = NA,
                       GROUP4_PROP = NA,
                       GROUP5_N = NA,
                       GROUP5_PROP = NA)
```

I have a dataframe called 'data' and I wish to create a dataframe or datatable that presents the COUNT(_N) of each variable by GROUP and also the weighted proportion (_PROP) for each variable for each group using the variable WEIGHT in the dataframe called 'data'. This is a probability weight that is given to me to get representative estimates.

Comment: Could you please explain how to compute prop variables using weight?

Comment: @Duck I am not quite sure actually but that is one of the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE))[, 
  c(list(N = .N), lapply(.SD, weighted.mean, WEIGHT)), 
 GROUP, .SDcols = CAT:MOUSE], id.var = c('GROUP', 'N'), 
   variable.name = 'Animal'), Animal  ~ 
        paste0('GROUP_', GROUP), value.var = c('value', 'N'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you are trying to do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(GROUP) %>%
  summarise(across(CAT:MOUSE, list(N = ~n(), 
                                   PROP = ~weighted.mean(., WEIGHT)))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-GROUP, 
               names_to = c('Animal', 'prop'), 
               names_sep = '_') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(GROUP, prop), values_from = value, 
              names_prefix = 'GROUP_')

# A tibble: 4 x 11
#  Animal GROUP_1_N GROUP_1_PROP GROUP_2_N GROUP_2_PROP GROUP_3_N
#  <chr>      <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 CAT          200            5       200            1       200
#2 DOG          200            5       200            2       200
#3 FOX          200            1       200            3       200
#4 MOUSE        200            2       200            1       200
# … with 5 more variables: GROUP_3_PROP <dbl>, GROUP_4_N <dbl>,
#   GROUP_4_PROP <dbl>, GROUP_5_N <dbl>, GROUP_5_PROP <dbl>
```

The `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` step is to get data in the same format as shown in `data_WANT` and they are not necessary to perform the calculation.